# Variable within variable - PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if a folder is empty or not.

I use an Apache server and a Windows 10 operating system.

What's the problem with my code ?

```
function is_dir_empty($dir) {
  if (!is_readable($dir)) return NULL; 
  return (count(scandir($dir)) == 2);
}

$dir = "C:/Users/name/.spyder/Python2/data/$day-$month-$year/emptyFolder";
print "<br>$dir<br>";
if (is_dir_empty($dir)) {
  echo "the folder is empty"; 
}else{
  echo "the folder is NOT empty";
}
```

Comment: You really need to specify, what problem you are receiving.

Comment: It does not work. I think there's a problem with quotation marks.

Comment: WHAT does not work? What do you expect to happen? For all we know you might be expecting a rocket launch.

Comment: The folder is empty and it prints out that it is not empty.

Comment: We would love to help, but we do not know what are the contents of your directory, or what are the contents of your PHP variables: $day, $month, $year and $dir.

Comment: The variables contain only integers.

Comment: Generally the folder has pictures, in which case the folder is empty

Comment: This program works fine using a different directory on my local machine. It seems like your problem is with $day $month and $year. If you echo those out what do you get?

Comment: TNX kalenpw....